# How to use YouTubePlayerSupportFragment with RecyclerView.ViewHolder

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am implementing `YouTubePlayerSupportFragment` in `RecyclerView.ViewHolder`, the videos are loading from firebase. The method to charge is `setUrlVideo()`.

```
public void setUrlVideo(final String URLvideo, final Context context) 
 {
    FrameLayout field = (FrameLayout) mView.findViewById(R.id.youtube_fragment);

    if(!"WithOutVideo".equals(URLvideo)){ //If is diferent

        YouTubePlayerSupportFragment youTubePlayerFragment = YouTubePlayerSupportFragment.newInstance();
        youTubePlayerFragment.initialize("AIzaSyCCySPG-sCKd17cHrWiZ5pJjZ-a7JoS6xo",
                new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider,
                                                        YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {
                        if (!b) {
                            YPlayer = youTubePlayer;
                            //YPlayer.setFullscreen(true);
                            YPlayer.cueVideo(URLvideo);
                            //YPlayer.play();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider,
                                                        YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {

                        String error = youTubeInitializationResult.toString();
                        Toast.makeText(context, R.string.failYoutube, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                });

        FragmentTransaction transaction = ((MainActivity)context).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.add(field, youTubePlayerFragment).commit();

    }
}
```

The error is the following:

```
Error:(88, 24) error: no suitable method found for add(FrameLayout,YouTubePlayerSupportFragment)
method FragmentTransaction.add(Fragment,String) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; FrameLayout cannot be converted to Fragment)
method FragmentTransaction.add(int,Fragment) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; FrameLayout cannot be converted to int)
```

Comment: Check your args for add https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html

Comment: I  am pretty sure you will stumble upon out of memory error if you use YoutubeFragment inside Recyclerview/listview. Please look into that perspective as well.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers.

The APP runs when I change the last line of
transaction.add (field, youTubePlayerFragment) .commit ();

to

transaction.add (R.id.youtube_fragment, youTubePlayerFragment) .commit ();

However it hangs when, inside the RecyclerView.ViewHolder it reaches the position where the video should appear.